# UICollectionView: NSInternalInconsistencyException attempt to delete section 0, but there are only 0 sections before the update in Realm notification

Tags: uicollectionview, realm

This crash only occurs when collectionView is empty before insertion or will be empty after deletion and only happen when insertion and deletion occur in view controller other than where collectionView is and as soon as insertion deletion happen i pop the controller and collectionView controller is visible.

So here is the scenario.

I have one section in collectionView let it be Controller1.

I push from Controller1 to another controller let it be Controller2.

At Controller2 i delete the object from realm and pop the viewController.

Now realm fires notification to Controller1 which tries to delete section 0 but gets NSInternalInconsistencyException.

I cross check viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear if i was reloading data but there isn't anything.

So basically if collectionView gets empty it automatically reload.

Does anyone has an idea why this happen?

Ok this only happens on physical devices and not on simulator. Now i am very curious to know why this actually happens.

Comment: Are you calling `reloadData()` when the `.initial` notification is fired? That's quite important to ensure your UICollectionView state is synchronized with Realm's.

Comment: Yes i am calling reloadData() when the .initial notification is fired.

Comment: I think you description was not clear. For example, you had `collectionView`, `Controller1`, `Controller2` and `the viewController`. What were these? Did you mix up `controller` with `view`?

Comment: @OwenZhao Controller1 is the collectionViewController and Controller2 is just a UIViewController. I push from Controller1 to controller2 and delete an object there and then pop the viewController. And there comes the error.

Comment: @jpsim i have found the actual error. Its with collectionView. If collectionView has 0 section then on viewWillAppear it will call prepareLayout of my custom collectionView layout. Now i need some way to stop that.

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem. Could you please post an SO answer once you've identified the correct fix in your code, in case someone else lands on this in the future? Thanks!

Comment: @jpsim sure i will. Currently i am doing a workaround where i dismiss controller after a pause of 0.3 second so that realm notification should be fired first and then dismiss the controller which handle the problem.